# Can you create Wordpress pages outside of the Wordpress subdirectory? Either at the root or another subdirectory?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, woocommerce

Client has a custom CMS that runs on the root and a Wordpress store in a subdirectory called "store".

https://www.example.com/store/cool-physical-product/

They want to add Wordpress content only accessible to users who purchase access from the Wordpress store, but it's visually clunky to add all of this content under the /store/ subdirectory naming scheme:

https://www.example.com/store/how-to-tame-your-dragon-during-a-pandemic/

Is there a way to cleanly accomplish something like this -- where both products and content are served from the Wordpress installation in the /store/ subdirectory, but only the products have the "store" name in the url?

https://www.example.com/store/cool-physical-product/
https://www.example.com/blog/how-to-tame-your-dragon-during-a-pandemic/

- or alternately -

https://www.example.com/store/cool-physical-product/
https://www.example.com/how-to-tame-your-dragon-during-a-pandemic/

WooCommerce runs the store, and it looks like it has independent permalinking, so I can do something where products all go to /store/product and everything else goes to /store/blog/title, but is there a way to rewrite the URL for /store/blog/title so that it looks like /blog/title or simply /title to the user without breaking Wordpress's control of those pages?

---

An alternate solution to this problem might be to create a separate Wordpress instance under the /blog subdirectory and use some kind of multisite user synchronization to hold it all together, but I'd much prefer the way I described it above if that's possible.

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: _"or simply /title"_ - that will hardly be possible, if you don't have a way of distinguishing such top-level URLs from those that should be handled by the custom CMS.

Comment: True, that could be complicated. Something like /blog/title/ would be sufficient, I think.